# Making a BPMN model more collaborative

Tags: bpmn

I am trying to make a bpmn for project, this projects has multiple teams (say 20), the teams are self-organizing and use scrum as a process model. At the end of each sprint all the teams have a sync meeting to see what is done.

The problem is that the teams work in different directions, and are doing large amount of unnecessary, overlapping work. This is due to little to no contact in the beggining of the sprints and then familiarize themselves with the others work at the end.

Under you will see the current BPMN diagram

[image]

Some ideas I have to help this is a shared documentation routines, definition of what is done and common testing routines and inter-team meeting, shared backlog. shared priortization task board.

I belive these will help the teams understand what the everyone are doing.

My question is, since it will be to much making pools for each team, is it allowed to make a pool just for one team representing all the teams as over, and make a pool where 'all' the teams meet to do the collaboration.

And when should this collaboration be done, before the sprint, after, in the middle? How can i represent this in a BPMN?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course, you can draw one collaboration for representing any team.

When to collaborate?

I think, your problem is not really with how to draw your BPMN, but the very process you try to represent.
Looks like your organization is in serious need for a good SCRUM coaching/counseling.